# Google translate API with Matlab

Tags: matlab, unicode

How I can translate from Arabic to English using Google API with MATLAB?

I tried to translate from Arabic language to English language using Google API with MATLAB. I use the following codes:
code number 1:

```
url = 'http://translate.google.com/translate_t';
page = urlread(url, 'get' {'v', '1.0','ie', 'UTF8','oe', 'UTF8','q', native2unicode('مرحبا','utf8'), ...
'langpair', ['ar' '|' 'en']});
```

code Number 2:

```
url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate';
page = urlread(url, 'get', {'v', '1.0','q', 'مرحبا', ...
    'langpair', ['ar' '|' 'en']});
```

But unfortunately, I didn't get the assumed result.

The result should be 'hello'

Comment: How I can translate using Google API with MATLAB? Arabic to English

Comment: I tried both but dosent working.

Comment: It seemed that first I have to convert to hexadecimal, but I dont know how to convert from string to hexadecimal in MATLAB. Any Idea appreciated.

Comment: what errors do you get? post the errors and the contents of `page` if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think the third argument in your call to urlRead may be faulty. From the documentation for urlRead:

```
str = urlread(URL,method,{Name,Value}) passes data to the server using a method of 'get' or 'post'. Specify the data to send with one or more Name,Value pair arguments.
```

It is mentioned that the `{Name, Value}` are pairs. Looking at the way you have invoked urlRead, there are a large number of values where there should be pairs. That seems to be the problem at first glance.

But, to be sure, it would be nice if you could post the error log or contents of page too.

Comment: page =

{"responseData": {"translatedText":""}, "responseDetails": null, "responseStatus": 200}

Comment: I think the error come because the Google API cannot read the Arabic word, it is a kind of Unicode problem. How I can convert Arabic word in MATLAB to type accepted by Google API

Comment: @nona: A responseStatus of 200 indicates that the request has succeeded. If it was a unicode problem, try to lookup the unicode for Arabic here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_%28Unicode_block%29. Specify it in your function call with \u<unicode>. So, `alif` in the end context would be \uFE8E and so on. Your string should consist of a string of these characters. Try that out too.

Comment: I did the following page = urlread(url, 'get', {'v','1.0','ie','UTF8','oe','UTF8','q','\uFE8E\uFE92\uFEA3\uFEAE\uFEE3', ...'langpair', ['ar' '|' 'en']});
??? Error using ==> vertcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

Comment: @nona: Did you try to remove the `...` from your command above? I tried that on octave, and got the following result: `page = {"responseData": {"translatedText":"\\ UFE8E \\ uFE92 \\ uFEA3 \\ uFEAE 
\\ uFEE3"}, "responseDetails": null, "responseStatus": 200}`